# IOS login screen before tab-controller view

Tags: xcode

I am still newbie for IOS Developing, i want to create a login page by MoralViewcontroller.

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{

     UITabBarController *tabBarController;   }

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController * tabBarController
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{    
  // Override point for customization after app launch 

  [window addSubview:tabBarController. view];   
  [window makeKeyAndVisible];
  LoginViewController *loginView=[[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];

  [tabBarController.view presentModelViewcontroller: loginView animated:YES];

}
```

However, the login view cannot be shown, I think I define wrongly for tabBarController, but I don't know what wrong with it. Can anyone please advise me? I am doing IOS 5.

Thanks alot..

Answer (score 4):

I'd present a loginView controller from the rootView of the tabBarController.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   //You can also do this inside a conditional statement, if needed
   LoginViewController *loginView=[[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.view presentModelViewcontroller:loginView animated:YES];

}
```

And here is the second way

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder {

 LoginViewController *loginView;  
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) LoginViewController *loginView;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
{
// Override point for customization after app launch
self.loginView=[[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
[window addSubview:loginView. view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

LoginViewController.m

Call this method on successful login.

```
-(IBAction)login:(id)sender
{
//init tabbar with subviews;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] initW....];
    [self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}
```

I prefer first method, because in that you will be retaining the tabBarController in AppDelegate.

Comment: thanks for your help Krrish. How do i set the rootView of the tabBarController? because currently i added tabBarController in storyboard, but i have no idea how to define the tabBarController for it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to add the Loginviewcontroller to the window.And then you have to add the tabbarcontroller to the LoginViewController when the login button clicked.

Comment: hi sri, thanks for your reply, can you explain more detail for it? thanks alot :)

Comment: It means in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method add the loginviewcontroller to the Window.And in the app delegate write a method like this  - (void)showTabBar{
 [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
 [loginviewController.view removeFromSuperview];
}.call the above method when you click the submit or login button in the loginviewcontroller

Comment: sorry to bother you. the startup page is TabBarController and present moralview for login page?