# UIViewController to UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view controller named `LoginViewController` which is of type, `UIVewController.` After a user loggs in, I want to transfer that view to a UITabBarController which consists of `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController.`

I try to do that using the following:

```
- (void)switchView {
    FirstViewController *firstView = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:firstView animated:YES];
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Is it because I'm not considering the whole UITabBarController?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should show UITabBarController:

```
- (void)switchView {
    FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabController.viewControllers = @[firstViewController, secondViewController];
    [self presentViewController:tabController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: That still does not switch the view. If it helps I'm using a storyboard.

Comment: updated answer. But you can also easy achieve it via storyboard segues

Comment: Look at the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174154/ios-login-screen-before-tab-controller-view

Answer (score 0):

After successful login, you could do something like the following and set the `UITabBarController` to be the new root `UIViewController` for your app.

In your `AppDelegate.m`

```
UITabBarController *tabController = [UITabBarController alloc] init];
[myTabBarController setViewControllers: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstViewController, secondViewController, nil]];

- (void)switchViewAfterSuccessfulLogin {
   if (![[[self window] rootViewController] isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]){
     [self.window setRootViewController:tabController];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should consider the UITabBarController. You could do this via the storyboard.

1. Select the `FirstViewController` in storyboard.
2. Go to Editor->Embed in->Tab Bar Controller. This would create a Tab Bar Controller `TabBarController`.
3. Add a relationship segue from `TabBarController` to `SecondViewController`.
4. Create a Push Segue from `LoginViewController` to `TabBarController`